# Post method not working in nodejs, I don't know why

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database-connection, ejs

**Here is my index.js which is entry point of my nodejs Application**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 2000;
require('./db/connection');
const Login = require('./model/LoginSchema');
const candidateControllers = require('./controllers/candidateController');

const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, './templates/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', templatePath);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());



// Routes
app.get('/dashboard', candidateControllers.getCandidate);
app.get('/candidate', candidateControllers.renderAddCandidate);
app.post('/candidate', candidateControllers.addCandidate);
app.get('/edit/:id', candidateControllers.editCandidate);
app.get('/delete/:id', candidateControllers.deleteCandidate);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register');
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const newLogin = new Login({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  newLogin
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.redirect('/login');
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      res.status(500).send(e.message + ' Sorry, something went wrong');
    });
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { name, password } = req.body;

  Login.findOne({ name: name, password: password })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
      } else {
        res.send('User not found');
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('Error while Login' + err));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Connecting to Server at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**My Atlas mongoDB connection file**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = `mongodb+srv://ishan:ishan@cluster0.oqweerf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
mongoose.connect(uri).then(() => console.log("Connected Successful!")).catch((e) => console.log("Connection failed" + e));



module.exports = mongoose;
```

**Here is candidateSchema file candidateSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const candidateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
    },
    num:{
        type: Number,
    },
},{timestamps: true})


const Candidate = mongoose.model('Candidate',candidateSchema);

module.exports = Candidate;
```

**This is my candidateController file candidateController.js**

```
  const Candidate = require("../model/candidateSchema");

  const renderAddCandidate = (req, res) => {
    res.render("addCandidate");
  };

  const getCandidate = (req, res, next) => {
    Candidate.find({})
      .then((candidates) => {
        res.render("index", { candidates });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send(err.message + " Sorry, failed to retrieve candidates.");
      });
  };

  const addCandidate = (req, res) => {

    const candidate = new Candidate({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      num: req.body.num
    });

      candidate.save()
      .then(() => {
          res.redirect("/dashboard");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send(err.message + " Sorry, something went wrong.");
      });
      console.log(req.body);
  };
  console.log(addCandidate);


  const editCandidate = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Candidate.findByIdAndUpdate(id)
      .then((userCandidates) => {
        res.render("editCandidate", {
          userCandidates: userCandidates,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send(err.message + "Sorry, Not able to update candidate");
      });
  };

  const deleteCandidate = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Candidate.findByIdAndDelete(id)
      .then(() => {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send(err.message + "Sorry, Not able to Delete candidate");
      });
  };

  module.exports = {
    getCandidate,
    addCandidate,
    renderAddCandidate,
    editCandidate,
    deleteCandidate,
  };
```

**This is my addCandidate.ejs template engine file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Add Candidate Here</h1>
    <form
      action="/candidate"
      method="post"
      style="
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50%;
        gap: 20px;
      "
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
      <label for="">Name: </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        placeholder="Candidate Name"
      />
      <label for="">Email: </label>
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Candidate Email"
      />
      <label for="">Number: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="num"
        placeholder="Phone no."
      />

      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note: My database connection is ok, when i try to post candidates , in my atlas-cloud i can see candidate_id and updated_at field but some how name, email and phonenumber field is not recognize**

**Help me with this code**

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
const {
    getCandidate,
    renderAddCandidate,
    addCandidate,
    editCandidate,
    deleteCandidate,
} = require('./controllers/candidateController');

app.get('/dashboard', getCandidate);
app.get('/candidate', renderAddCandidate);
app.post('/candidate', addCandidate);
app.get('/edit/:id', editCandidate);
app.get('/delete/:id', deleteCandidate);
```